# Some chat users have gravatars with no hash in the URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, gravatar

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2925837/hasan-alaca
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2758236/lugia101101

Both have this gravatar URL: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

I've already seen this behaviour a few days ago. Both users have proper gravatar identicons on Stack Overflow and one of them has an email set so it's not caused by the fact that the other one does not have an email set. I tried refreshing the chat profile of the user with the email to be sure chat knows about the email, too.

Comment: Maybe the email was set only after joining chat for the first time?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd (re edit) That's "SO proper" as opposed to "SO chat"; it has nothing to do with the "proper" earlier in the sentence.

Comment: @michaelb958 it's very confusing then, should be "on Stack Overflow main site" or something like that. I'm sure the OP won't hesitate to rollback though. :)

Comment: +1 - I have also seen users with the same gravatar at times. I was unable to identify the cause so I did not post.

Comment: That gravatar looks familiar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; there was an API change in the internal communications between chat and stackoverflow - it was still returning *a* url, so the change wasn't flagged - it just wasn't always a *useful* one. This has been fixed and will be deployed next build.